# Is it possible to prevent a mapping from being repeated with a prefix number (vim range)?

Tags: repeated-commands, movement

Sometimes it is possible to accidentally hit some numeric keys. I have a lot of binds and for most of them there is nothing to be gained by allowing them to repeat with a prefix. Let's suppose that there are some commands that can be semi-disastrous (ones that make `tmux` calls) if they get repeated. Is there a way to prevent this behavior for a mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the command line, like so:

```
nnoremap <LEADER>t :!echo "Yay"<CR>
```

(just an example)

You can add `<C-u>` after the `:` to erase all undesired characters:

```
nnoremap <LEADER>t :<C-u>!echo "Yay"<CR>

" Also works with `<CMD>` in neovim:

nnoremap <LEADER>t <CMD>!echo "Yay"<CR>
```

---

What happens is that by default, when you hit numbers followed by `:`, a **range** will automatically be added to your command by default.

A range basically allows you to run a command on multiple lines at once, For example:

```
:1,5s/this/that/g
```

Executes the substitute command on the lines 1 to 5.  Line 5 is included.
The range is always placed before the command.

(*above example from the vim doc*)

---

To learn more about ranges:

- `:help 10.3`
- `:help cmdline-ranges`

Comment: This really works! Thanks. It just nukes the stuff that the `:` includes for you (like `:.,.+2`, could someone explain what that is/does?) if you type a number before the colon.

Comment: I updated my answer 

Comment: Thank you! Now that I have the proper terminology I updated the question title as well.